# Can I get 2FA for my private domain e-mail account?

Tags: email, multi-factor, account-security

Is it possible to somehow get 2FA for my e-mail accounts even if they're hosted on custom / private domains? (e.g mymail@mycooldomain.com and not gmail)

Comment: It really depends on how your system is built, but you might take a look at this for some inspiration and to get an idea of the right direction: https://serverfault.com/questions/428762/2-factor-authentication-for-dovecot-postfix-ssh-pam

Answer (score 1):

It depends what email service you're using. I'm using Office 365 with my private domain name which does support MFA so I can enable it on my email account(s).

Comment: Are you then hosting your domain / website over Office 365, since I presume their service need to have access to your domain for this to work?

Comment: @user9853113 No, the registrar, name servers / DNS, and email services can all be seperate. You'll just need to create the DNS Resource Records pointing to Office 365 for its various services (domain name ownership verification, inbound email delivery, outbound email authentication, AutoDiscover, MDM, etc) in the domain's authoritative name servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you expect to enable 2FA on your web server not in web site. It is possible on Apache server, when you use ssh.

I think below link will be helpfull for you.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/two-factor-authentication-system-apache-and-ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the server, then yes eg: https://www.wikidsystems.com/support/how-to/how-to-configure-webmail-for-wikid-strong-authentication/.  If not, then no.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not running the server. it's just hosted on some random website host service. Am I understanding it correctly that some hosting services do actually provide this server for e-mail accounts though?